# $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not sure how to close the contour. As the poles lie on the imaginary axis, taking contour only on the negative x part will exclude the poles. However the integral should be finite. How to go about it?

Comment: What makes you think this integral is finite? The integrand behaves like $1/x$, as $x$ goes to $-\infty$, which is not integrable.

Comment: the integral itself is 1/2(ln(x^2+a^2)). Of course it will diverge in the given limits.

Answer (score 1):

SquirtleSquad, Oct 11 '16 at 6:20 answered:

> What makes you think this integral is finite? The integrand behaves like $1/x$, as $x$ goes to $−\infty$, which is not integrable.

Lelouch, Oct 11 '16 at 6:33 answered:

> The integral itself is $(\ln(x^2+a^2))/2$. Of course it will diverge in the given limits.

Comment: I wish more posts were written community-style like this. Works fantastically.